# counter, loop controller & foreach loop controller in jmeter

Tags: variables, jmeter, counter

facing a problem as below

1. I have a http request & in response header, I am getting a key, value as range: items=0-99/3876. how to extract the range 0,99 & 3876 as jmeter variable from postprocessor (like regular expression).
2. I want to create a loop which runs for like 39 times (which is like round to the no 3876) to next 100/1000's to vary the range as 0-99,100-199, ... to 3800-3900.. for next http requests in loop with the counter. which increments by value of 100.

I have gone with the below procedure:-

1. http sampler to get the response header :- range: items=0-99/3846
2. extracted the values 0,99 & 3846 as jmeter values from different regular expressions extractor (which should have been done by single processor only)
3. Want to get the loop count value as 3846/100 == 38 +1
4. Now setting the counter with starting range as 0 with increment value of 100 & ending range as 99 with increment as 100 from the jmeter variables.
5. now implement the counter variables as http header foe all the next headers.

Comment: how to get all the output variables from a single extractor. Like all these foo=0
bar=99
baz=3846 variables I am fetching it from 3 different extractors as regular expression extractor.   range: items=0-99/3846

Answer (score 0):

Given you have the following [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html):

```
foo=0
bar=99
baz=3846
```

you can use [__jexl3() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__jexl3) to calculate dynamic number of loops like:

```
${__jexl3(${baz}/100+1,)}
```

the function can be placed directly to the [Loop Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller)'s "Loop Count" input:

[image]

this way given your data Loop Controller will run its children 39 times.

If you want to configure a [Counter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Counter) it would be something like:

[image]

See [How to Use a Counter in a JMeter Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-counter) article for more details if needed.

The variable declared in the Counter can be used in the [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager):

[image]